# What do we do with questions that are already answered somewhere else on SE?

Tags: discussion, faq, exact-duplicates

The title kind of says it all. I'm asking, because this
[Performing certain operations without clearing register](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/122/performing-certain-operations-without-clearing-the-clipboard) question seems to be sufficiently answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255/in-vim-is-there-a-way-to-delete-without-putting-text-in-the-register here.

- Close
- Downvote
- Copy answer
- ?

Answer (score 33):

None of the above.

## Write a better answer.

Closing is only for questions that are unanswerable or that are off-topic. The fact that a question has been answered elsewhere is irrelevant.

Lack of research is a valid reason to downvote, but just because the question has been asked somewhere else on the Internet doesn't imply a lack of research. (For one thing, has this elsewhere question been answered satisfactorily?)

Copying the answer is a possibility¹, if there's an answer that's really great, but it shouldn't happen too often. The whole point for this site to exist is to be a better place for vi questions than SO. If SO is the place to go for vi answers, there's no point in having a site dedicated to vi.

Many vi answers on SO are somewhat minimalistic. Don't just copy an answer that says “press `kkjjhlhl21i`”: explain why it works, link to the manual, suggest additional plugins that help with the task, discuss portability across vi implementations, etc.

Especially in the early beta, don't be content with adequate answers. Aim for awesome.

¹  <sub>You may always copy Stack Exchange answers, [with attribution](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).</sub>

Comment: ... and then read **[Respect the community – your own, and others’](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/)**

Comment: and if you copy-paste an answer, at least have the dignity to (1) attribute it (the licence actually forces you to do so), (2) make it community-wiki.

Comment: [Relevant discussion in comments of this question](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/310/how-do-i-make-opening-new-tabs-the-default)

Comment: This, absolutely. Remember that part of the reason earlier vim proposals got shut down was over concern that it would drain users from existing sites where vim questions were accepted (SO, SU). If this site is going to succeed, it can't just serve as a link-repository to (or partial mirror of) SO or SU.

Answer (score -1):

I think the correct response might be to link the off-site response in a comment (although I could be convinced that linking it in an answer is better).

I don't think that copying an answer is a good idea.  It feels plagiarism-y (despite the fact that it's [all under CC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/12528)).  Plus, which answer should a google search turn up?

Writing a better answer is...well, better, but sometimes that's just not feasible.

Comment: Not many questions on [SO] or [SU] get really thorough answers, they are mostly one-to-two-lines introduced by "this works" or "I'd do this". Adding more explanation and context is a big improvement, and in vast majority of cases there is a lot of space for that.

Comment: @yo'
Great, when that's the case, but I've already seen 4 or 5 questions today which had fairly thorough answers on SO.

Comment: If you ad a link to them (both on Vim.SE and the dupe on SO) to this your answer, it'll be great! (It would make the discussion about the proper solution easier.)

Comment: @yo' Are you suggesting that we link (in a comment or otherwise) **reciprocally** on both SO and vi.SE?  Interesting idea.  I can see how that would help.  I've already been trying to link _to_ SO answers here.

Comment: No, sorry, I didn't mean that. You say "I've seen 4 or 5 questions" -- can you tell us here which ones are they?

Comment: Ah.  Just running down the 'hot' page I found [this](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/221/open-md-files-as-markdown), [this](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/84/how-can-i-copy-text-to-the-system-clipboard-from-vim), and [this](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/130/how-to-comment-out-a-set-of-lines-which-are-selected-in-visual-mode).

For the first two I, just now, added comments linking the SO answers.  The third I had answered earlier today with links to SO.

Comment: Ah I see. well, one of them is actually a dupe directly here, of my question.