# Should we encourage asking questions that are already on another SE site?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Before vi.SE entered private beta, many of us found answers to legitimate vi/vim questions in other sites, such as SO, tex.SE, etc.

- Should we encourage vi.SE users to scavenge other SE sites for questions tagged as [vi](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vi)/[vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim)?
- If not, should we discourage it? And how?

See also: [What do we do with questions that are already answered somewhere else on SE?](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45/what-do-we-do-with-questions-that-are-already-answered-somewhere-else-on-se)

Comment: Thanks @durron597, I'll rephrase to focus on the parts that are *not* covered in the other answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, we should not encourage people to "steal" content from other sites, that is

- disrespectful to that other community, and
- does not help prove that a vim SE answers fill any kind of need within the SE network that is not already handled perfectly fine by SO/SU/et cetera.

It also leads to cross-posting among SE sites, which is [not cool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @josh-petrie, except for the following points.

**TL;DR**: Allow the question on vi.SE if the user is relatively new to SE itself -- this site *is* the most apropos place to ask. And also allow it if it is similar but not fully answered elsewhere (SO).

(A) Say a user new to SE overall has a question about Vim. They are more likely to search on this site, for the fact that it's the site's focus. Now have the user write a question. No similar questions appear on the right. They will think it is "new" to the entire stack, and continue to post it. In this case, we should answer it best we can in purely Vim terms... attempting to write an answer different than what is on SO.

(B) Similar to above... Say someone familiar with SE searches for a question first on SO. It helps them out 95%. That other 5% is still crucial. At first glance, the new question on vi.SE will look the same. BUT DO NOT CROSS-LINK IMMEDIATELY! You take the time to read it, and find a way to answer it with a different perspective, a vi perspective.