# Should I delete my question?

Tags: discussion

**Related**: [What do we do with questions that are already answered somewhere else on SE](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45/what-do-we-do-with-questions-that-are-already-answered-somewhere-else-on-se).

I recently asked [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3467/can-i-use-the-mouse-for-folding-unfolding-in-gvim?noredirect=1#comment4846_3467).

Before asking, I tried googling and searching in vi.SE but failed to find something useful.

I admit I don't quite recall *what* I typed into google, but I do remember checking questions tagged with [mouse + folding](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mouse+folding) in vi.SE.

The few comments (and one downvote) assume I did none of the above.
Which is understandable, really, seeing as my current attempts to google all lead to the [suggested answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924093/gvim-fold-toggle-using-mouse).

I do understand that I'm expected to show some effort before asking, which is not apparent.

**Should I delete my question?**

Comment: Uh, looking at the answers, I think it's the first paragraph of Ingo's answer that really answers your question. That is, I don't think you need to map.

Comment: Secondly, I'm willing to believe you put in a good-faith effort at research, so I'd say don't delete.

Comment: Agreed, don't delete. Now that your question exists here, the next time someone searches directly on vi.SE for this info, they'll find your question and the link to SO. Later, someone might even directly answer with more information as well, making yours the better answered question.

Comment: Our ultimate goal is really to make Vi.SE the ultimate resource for (V)im questions.  If you found your answer elsewhere and it was a high-quality question, maybe just answer your own questions (giving credit where it's due, of course).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over the past year that I have been active on Ask Ubuntu (another SE site that has a lot of overlap with other sites, in this case Unix & Linux), I have, on quite a few occasions, come across questions that have been answered, and *answered well*, on U&L or SO, or some other SE site.

The general response I have seen from people who found the questions on sister sites is to quote these answers (or combine and condense them), perhaps marking it as community-wiki, if they have the time (and if think it is on-topic). If not, a comment (and a vote to close if they think it isn't).

The general response from people who didn't find such posts was to post the best answer they could.

On occasion, though, people would delete their question when given a link to such posts on other SE sites.

In this case, I'm going to go with option 1.