# I answered a vim question on SO that is not here, should I make a self-answer here?

Tags: discussion, answers, asking-questions

I am trying to advocate *vi.SE* by going out on SO, answering Vim questions and then directing people towards us here on *vi.SE*.  Yet, I encountered a situation in which [a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38247312/how-can-i-view-ebcdic-formatted-files-in-vim/38255604#38255604) has no equivalent here on *vi.SE*.

I am aware of [What do we do with questions that are already answered somewhere else on SE?](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45/what-do-we-do-with-questions-that-are-already-answered-somewhere-else-on-se) But it would be rather difficult for me to beat my own answer.

Is it the correct action to **make a better question** and then extend my own answer as a self-answer to it?

The question I'm thinking of asking (and self-answering) is "*How do I open files in exotic encodings in Vim?*"

Answer (score 3):

I'm still pretty new to the SE ecosystem, but I don't see the harm in replicating your answer here, *especially* if you can improve the original question. Each site exists to collect great questions and even better answers about its particular scope, so having a good Vi-related question and answer on the Vi & Vim SE, regardless of their existence on another SE (or even the internet as a whole) just seems correct to me.

As Gilles said himself in the meta discussion you linked:

> The whole point for this site to exist is to be a better place for vi questions than SO. If SO is the place to go for vi answers, there's no point in having a site dedicated to vi.

So as far as I'm concerned, absolutely go for it. It all makes this stack a better place.